# How to insert a Spanish Google Calendar in a Full Calendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need to insert the festive days in my Full Calendar. I have a Full Calendar with some events and I have to insert the festive days. The google calendar is: es.spain#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com.

I am trying to do this but I can't. I have this code but the events don't load:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            lang : 'es',
            witdh : "100%",
            header : {
                left : 'prev,next today',
                center : 'title',
                right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            googleCalendarApiKey : '642280338060-ocq7lmaa1boo8c9na8e0vp5l0a68itus.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            events : {
                googleCalendarId : 'es.spain#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
            }
        });
```

I follow all the instructions on https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the google calendar demo from https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.0.1/demos/gcal.html this worked. The API key you posted doesn't look like a proper one (not that you should post your personal API key here)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',

    // Spain Holidays
    events: 'es.spain#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',

    eventClick: function(event) {
        // opens events in a popup window
        window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
        return false;
    }
});
```